# How to populate a complex react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dynamic

```
   const [content, setContent] = useState([
    {main: '', li:[''] },
  ]);
```

i am looking for a way to add new items to content.li?
i have tried to push in using

```
Array.push('new')
```

but failed.
This is a dynamic form with a changeable amount of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like this:

```
const [content, setContent] = useState([
    {main: '', li:[''] },
  ]);

setContent([...content,"new" as any])
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the forum. any of these modifications to objects or arrays are valid as long as they are applied to a content clone, not content itself.

if you apply changes to original content, you are mutating state directly, which is an antipattern. second, array and object are reference based. when you change something inside and array/object you are not changing its reference (address in memory where it's located the object).

react wont look deep into objects to check what changes, it does a shallow verification instead. array content may differ, but since reference is the same `setContent(content)` will consider that `content` state is the same and won't perform state update.

in this way, everytime dealing with arrays/objects you need to clone it. spread operator is a popular way (given its cleaner syntax) to accomplish that:

```
  const nextContent = [...content] // content copy
  const item = nextContent[i] // i given object index to update
  const li = [ ...item.li, 'new' ] // new li
  const nextItem = { ...item, li } // object with updated Item
  nextContent[i] = nextItem
  setContent(nextContent)
```

the above will create a new array, with a different reference. it will spread content values into it. then add following values ('new') to the desired `li`. given it's a new reference, setContent will work as expected.

Comment: i am not looking for to update my content. what i wanted is content.li, the array inside content object. if you know how please help

Comment: ok, updated the answer for a specific li update.